# GeoServer create thematic from point to area

Tags: geoserver, thematic-map

I have some point data like first image. 
[image: I have this data]

I want create thematic with this data. But I can't create GeoServer style like this. [image: What I want]

You see data on map like this:
[image: This data which I have]

How can i create style which i see thematic image on this image? : [image: How can create thematic like this image]

I use heat map but heat map does not meet my request:
[image]

Comment: I searched a little more, the thematic type I want is called "IsoLine" or "IsoTherm". But I couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HeatMap WPS process as described in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation). You could also use the [Barnes Surface interpolation](https://docs.boundlessgeo.com/suite/1.1.1/cartography/rt/barnes.html).

Comment: Hi @Ian, i use heatmap thematic but i cant take result like this. You can see heatmap thematic with this link: https://ibb.co/HgKHhPs

Comment: please update your question to make it clearer

Comment: I change my request @Ian

Comment: Documentation for Barnes Surfaces here: https://docs.boundlessgeo.com/suite/1.1.1/cartography/rt/barnes.html

Comment: Hi @AndreaAime, i read documant and prepare new sld. Created a SQL Layer with this values (ID, GEOLOC, COLOR_CODE). Color Code is between -1 and 4. I set style below this: https://justpaste.it/23afj but it always return -1.
I added WPS on geoserver, and see BurnesSurface in Goeserver demos. I don't know if I need to install another plugin.